# For loop with Node js promise chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am very new to Node js and asynchronous programming seems difficult for me to grasp. I am using promise-mysql to make the flow synchronous but I have hit a road block with for loop inside of a chain of promise

I have a multiple choice question module. One table stores all the mcq questions and the other stores all the related choices for the questions. I am using the output of the first query as an input to the second query and so I did promise chaining as below

```
var mcqAll=[]
var sql_test_q_ans='select qId, q_text from questions'
    con.query(sql_test_q_ans)
    .then((result)=>{
      for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++)
      {
        ques=result[i]
        var sql_test_q_ops='SELECT op_text, op_id FROM mc_ops WHERE 
                             q_id='+result[i].q_id
        con.query(sql_test_q_ops)
        .then((resultOps)=>{
          mcqAll.push({i: ques, ops: resultOps})
          console.log(mcqAll)
         })
      }
    })
```

I am trying to create a javascript object array which would look something like this

```
[{q_text:'How many states in USA', q_ops:{1:25, 2:35, 3:45, 4:50}}
 {question2 and its options}
 {question3 and its options}....
]
```

When I run the above code the object populates all the question's options correctly but the same question is repeated in all the q_text for all questions.

```
[ { q_text: 'No of states in USA',
  [ {op_text: '25', mc_op_id: 113 },
    { op_text: '35', mc_op_id: 114 },
    { op_text: '45', mc_op_id: 115 },
    { op_text: '50', mc_op_id: 116}],
  { q_text: 'No of states in USA',
  [ {op_text: 'A', mc_op_id: 1 },
    { op_text: 'B', mc_op_id: 2 },
    { op_text: 'C', mc_op_id: 3 },
    { op_text: 'D', mc_op_id: 4}],
  { q_text: 'No of states in USA',
  [ {op_text: 'Yes', mc_op_id: 31 },
    { op_text: 'No', mc_op_id: 32 },
    { op_text: 'No sure', mc_op_id: 33 },
    { op_text: 'Might be', mc_op_id: 34}]
]
```

I feel like it has something to do with asynchronous flow since console.log before the second query gets printed in all before printing anything after the second query. Any insight would be appreciated

Edit: I added a sample output for better understanding. As seen in the output, the options change and get stored in the js object in the for loop but the question is updated for all the objects to the last question in the for loop

Comment: change *var i* to *let i* as var is function scoped so everything inside the for loop will share the same i and you have async call inside the loop, so loop completes first then event loop will start resolving async calls, as loop already completed so value of i will be length of array which will be used for all the async calls

Comment: Could you add a wrong output in order to understand better what is the data duplicated?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon added a sample output

Comment: @AZ_, I tried let i but it made not difference

Answer (score 2):

node js current working `async` and `await`, `still now use to async and await`, 
use this reference url: https://javascript.info/async-await

async and await is work as promise, `await is use to wait to execute script` 
example

```
let mcqAll=[]
let sql_test_q_ans='select qId, q_text from questions'
async function showAvatar() {
   let result = await con.query(sql_test_q_ans);
   if(result.length > 0){
      array.forEach((async function (item, index, result) {
        let q =  result[index];
        let sql_test_q_ops='SELECT op_text, op_id FROM mc_ops WHERE 
                             q_id='+result[index].q_id  
        let executeQuery = await con.query(sql_test_q_ops);    
        if(executeQuery.affectedRows > 0){
           mcqAll.push({index: q, ops: executeQuery})
           console.log(mcqAll);
        }
      });
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a scope problem here

This is an example to reproduce your problem:

`ques` is a global variable that is updated in the for-loop so, when the async code ends the execution will read the global variable with the last `ques = result[i]` value.

```js
'use strict'
const result = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const mcqAll = []
var ques
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  ques = result[i]
  var sql_test_q_ops = 'SELECT op_text, op_id FROM mc_ops WHERE q_id = ' + result[i].q_id
  query(sql_test_q_ops)
    .then(() => {
      mcqAll.push({ i: ques })
      console.log(mcqAll)
    })
}

function query() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100))
}
```

But, if you simply declare the `ques` like this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  const ques = result[i]
  const sql_test_q_op...
```

all will work.

It is a good practice to use `const` or `let` instead of `var` because the last one creates a global scoped variable that is dangerous.

---

Regarding your comment: the output is empty because this for-loop is sync, so you reply in sync way to the response.

An example on how to manage this case could be like this:

```js
'use strict'
const result = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const mcqAll = []

const promiseArray = result.map(ques => {
  const sql_test_q_ops = 'SELECT op_text, op_id FROM mc_ops WHERE q_id = ' + ques.q_id
  return query(sql_test_q_ops)
    .then(() => { mcqAll.push({ i: ques }) })
})

// Wait for all the query to complete before rendering the results
Promise.all(promiseArray)
  .then(() => {
    console.log({ mcqAll });
    res.render('mcqAllPage', { mcqAll })
  })
  .catch(err => res.send(500)) // this is an example

function query() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100))
}
```

Consider that there are many possibilities to implement this:

- use [for async iterator](https://medium.com/@nairihar/async-iteration-in-nodejs-v10-3c17dc00ed9f) to run query sequentially
- improve performance by run only one query with a `in` condition instead of a query for each `q_id` and manage the result with some code to group the results
- using the promise array as in the example

Go deeper and choose the one that fits best for your need.

Important: `.catch` always the promise chain!

Comment: Thank you so much @ManuelSpigolon, this helped me a lot, perfect answer. I had been struggling with this one. One more question. If I want to do res.render to a page with mcqAll object, at which point should I write it? res.render('mcqAllPage', {mcqAll}) Writing after for loop somehow doesn't work and sends in an empty array. Or am I missing something?