# how to use callback function in a for loop in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have defined three functions, which all use the Promise to return some values. The first function is to return the token by calling the database API, the second function is to return all the databases by using the token returned from the first function, the third function is to get the account access by using the info from previous two functions

```
function get_auth_token(){
    const  api_end_point = nebula_staging_url + "/api/v1/auth"

    var options = {
        url: api_end_point,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        auth: {
            'user': 'admin',
            'pass': 'password'}
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode==200){
            var token = JSON.parse(body)
            var auth_token = token["data"][0]["accessToken"]
            // console.log(auth_token)
            resolve(auth_token)

        }
        else{
            reject(error)
        }
    })
})
}


function get_all_tenants(access_token){
    var api_end_point = nebula_staging_url + "/api/v1/tenants"

    var options = {
        url: api_end_point,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "x-access-token": access_token
        },
        auth: {
            "user": "admin",
            "pass": "password"
        }
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode==200){
            var tenants = JSON.parse(body)
            resolve(tenants)

        }
        else{
            reject(error)
        }
    })
})
}


function get_account_access(tenant_id, access_token){
    var api_end_point = nebula_staging_url + "/api/v1/tenants/" + tenant_id + "/access"

    var options = {
        url: api_end_point,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "x-access-token": access_token}
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode==200){
            try{
                var tenants = JSON.parse(body)
                //console.log(tenants)
                resolve(tenants)
            }
            catch(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
        else{
            reject(error)
        }
    })
})
}

// Trying to print something info

get_auth_token().then(token => 
    get_all_tenants(token).then(tenants => {

        var count = 0 
        for(var i=0; j=tenants["data"].length,i<j; i++){

            if(tenants["data"][i]["name"].includes("PERF")){
                var tenant_id = tenants["data"][i]["id"]

                console.log("old_tenant_id", tenant_id)

                get_account_access(tenant_id, token).then(account_access => {

                    console.log("new_tenant_id", tenant_id)

                })
             }

       //break

       count = count + 1
       if(count==3){break}
    }

 }))
```

When I print all the old_tenant_id (outside of the get_account_access function), it prints the correct ones, However, the new_tenant_id only print the last one. the output looks like this:

[image]

It seems only the last tenant id go through the get_account_access function. I am very new to Nodejs, and I have a feeling to use callback function, However, I have no idea how to implement it in my case. Please be easy on me :)

Comment: https://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-10/advanced-promise-usage/

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use `Promise.all` to run all of your promises. Use the for loop to create an array of promises to run and then run them all together (asynchronously).

```
let tenantsPromise = [] // array to hold promises

for(var i=0; j=tenants["data"].length,i<j; i++){

            if(tenants["data"][i]["name"].includes("PERF")){
                var tenant_id = tenants["data"][i]["id"]

                console.log("old_tenant_id", tenant_id)
                tenantsPromise.push()
                get_account_access(tenant_id, token).then(account_access => {
                    console.log("new_tenant_id", tenant_id)
                    return tenant_id // return the new id
                })) // push your promises into the array
             }
            }

// and then run all of the promises at one time
Promise.all(tenantsPromise).then(function(new_ids){
    console.log(new_ids)

    // here you can do a for loop and see if the results are the same
    for(var i=0; j=tenants["data"].length,i<j; i++){

            if(tenants["data"][i]["name"].includes("PERF")){
                var tenant_id = tenants["data"][i]["id"]
                var new_id = new_ids["data"][i]["id"]
                console.log(`Ids equal? ${tenant_id===new_id}`)
           }

})
```

Check out the [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) docs.

Comment: @tagyourreit it did not solve my issue :( However, I want to new_tenant_id returns the same thing as the old_tenant_id.

Comment: You just need to compare new_ids (in the return of Promise.all) to the list of tenant ids.  I'll note this above in the code with an edit.

Comment: I have modified the code according to yours, however, it did not print any new_ids

Comment: You also don't need to parse the JSON if you are just returning the body.  `var tenants = JSON.parse(body); resolve(tenants)` can just be `resolve(body)`.

Comment: I modified your solution, it still equal to the new_tenant_id. However, I want it to equal to the old_tenant_id.

Answer (score 0):

[For loop with Node js promise chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372992/for-loop-with-node-js-promise-chaining)

This post solved my issue, As long as I use let instead of var, the new_tenant_id will be same as old_tenant_id

Comment: You can use `for await` loop in such scenarios: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of